# How to represent beams broken with rests in LilyPond

Tags: notation, rhythm, lilypond, beaming, rests

I'm trying to write the following in LilyPond notation:

[image: Two ways of representing a 16th rest in between two 16th notes. The first has the outer beam connecting the 16th notes, but the inner beam is broken. The second has both beams on the 16th notes connected.]

As shown in the circled parts of the image, there are two different ways of representing a beam that spans a sixteenth note – a sixteenth rest – a sixteenth note.

In one of them, the beam is broken at the rest, in the other it is not.

I am representing this as:

```
c16[ r16 c16]
```

This gives me the lower of the two patterns circled in the image.

But, how can I get the upper pattern with LilyPond notation?

Comment: Related: [Beams broken/unbroken with rests - meaning and usage](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/118733/beams-broken-unbroken-with-rests-meaning-and-usage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can typeset this using

```
\new RhythmicStaff
{
  \time 3/16
  16[ \once\set stemRightBeamCount = 1
      \once\set stemLeftBeamCount = 1
       r16 16]
  \time 9/16
  16[ r16 16] 16 16 r16 16 r r
}
```

and I don't see that using this at this place makes actual sense.

Comment: The `\once` commands don't do anything here.